# How to plot using multiple dataframes with Y axis being observations from another dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a dataframe where X axis is from say df1 and y axis has to be taken as observation from another dataframe df2. sample data frames given below.

```
df1
id    a    b    c
id1   1.5  1.3  2.1
id2   2.4  1.8  1.6
id3   1.5  1.9  2.3
...
...

df2
list    type    parm
1        a       xm
2        b       gh
3        c       tr
```

From above sample data frames I am plotting df1 (ID on X axis) with separate plots for variables a,b,c as below.

```
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = id, y = a)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
p1
p2 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = id, y = b)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
p2
p3 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = id, y = c)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
p3
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,ncol = 1)
```

My question is, is there a way to give y axis as input from df2 because the variables a, b, c in df1 are observations in type column in df2.

I tired to give as below

```
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = id, y = df2$type[1])) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
p1
```

But the values were not plotted.
And further these 3 variables can become 5 variables or even more like a,b,c,d,e,f when I run my main code and I want my plotting code to automatically pick y axis from df2 with their corresponding values in df1. 
Is there an easy way to plot it.

Comment: df2$type[1] will return a character vector. So you will have to use aes_string() . This is from my first view of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = data.frame( id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), a= 1:3, b = 3:5, c = 4:6)
df2 = data.frame(type = letters[1:3], parm = letters[11:13])
df2$type <- as.character(df2$type)

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes_string(x = "id", y = df2$type[1])) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
p1
```

[image: output from above code]

Comment: I used `aes_string` also but the values are not plotting

Comment: @ash could you check if class(df2$type) is factpr/character ? because I guess it must be a character.